# What is the best way to change the intro on a Contribution page based on URL?

Tags: drupal, developer

I have a contribution page that uses values passed via URL to track specific information about the source of the contribution.

www.domain.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=8&campaign=sponsorship&appeal=11&fund=child&amount=35.00

The `appeal` variable in the URL contains the nid (node id) for Drupal content. I would like to display image, first_name, and description of the child, pulled from this node.

Would a profile be used here or use the code extension created for tracking the source?

Comment: When you say "node" you mean a Drupal node?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  The node content type called sponsorship.  it contains information about a person, place, or thing that can be sponsored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (if I understand correctly what you are after) would be to create a view that displays the node *(or node's fields -- image, first_name, description)* as you want it using a Block display for the view. Set up a contextual argument for the node's `nid` which provides a default value using PHP code and pull the `appeal` variable from the URL, something like this:

```
check_plain($_GET['appeal');
```

Then simply display this block at the top of the `content` region in your default theme for the `civicrm/contribute/transact` path.

Comment: If your contextual filter drop down list for "Provide default value " does not contain "PHP Code" you will need to go to the modules and enable "PHP filter"